# Sitecore 7.2 Upgrade Media Library issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I upgraded Sitecore 7.1 to 7.2 and images with a space in the path are not working eg `/images/path 1/image1` not working but `/images/path1/image1` is working. I'm using

```xml
 <encodeNameReplacements>
      <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
 </encodeNameReplacements>
```

Any help will be really appreciated. I tried a solution explained [here](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-7-2-upgrade-encoding-media-library-item-names)
but didn't help

Comment: Are you only upgrading to 7.2 only? or you intend to upgrade to latest version (8.2)? Sitecore KB says this has been fixed in Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150427 (Update-3)

Comment: After using the KB article below, your media items with spaces, transformed into "-" still don't work? From reading that article, items that have a "-" in their names should fail. But items with spaces transformed into "-" should now work.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog post [here](http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/images-broken-after-upgrade-sitecore-7.5) which I think covers this situation. The problem as you know is related to the encodeNameReplacements. When I had this issue, I just renamed the items to not have spaces, but you can also follow this [Sitecore KB article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/998758).

Comment: My understanding of the issue is when you change the media prefix to `-/media` the encodenamereplacement also affects this part of the URL hence the issue. Not sure if the OP is also using this or not though.

Comment: I tried the sitecore fix but didn't work for me. Also, I've hundreds of media items that use space.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by renaming all the " " with "-" using Sitecore POwershell.

Comment: Sometimes the simple solutions are the best ;-)